# Remote debug a dotnet core application deployed on docker from windows in vs code

Tags: bash, docker, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging

Is there an easy way to remote debug a dotnet core application in vs code, where the application is deployed inside docker? I've tried using bash and its ssh as pipeProgram, but I meet problems like the remoteProcessPickerScript reading the motd and other kinds of errors. I've seen tutorials for azure and IIS, but I want to run my application in a Linux server, having docker engine.